# $AA^T$ rank and singularity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{m,n}$ and $m>n$. Can rank of $AA^T$ cannot be greater than rank of $A$? And is $AA^T$ singular matrix?

I think both of these are correct, since I tried some examples, but I can't prove them.

EDIT:

I've figured out that ranks have to be the same since $ker(A)=ker(AA^T)$.

Comment: So what have you tried for proving this?

Comment: No, that's impossible.  You may think of the rank-nullity theorem applied on A.

Comment: Maybe you can google The Cauchy－Binet  Formula/Theorem.